# My question correct, help me here?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is:
Calculate the integrals below by interpreting them in terms of area.

a) $\int_1^3(1+2x)dx$

b)$\int_2^5x^2dx$

I tried to respond as follows, attached below:

a)[image: Question A]

b)[image: Question B]

Are the graphic part of both questions correct?

Comment: Please put all relevant information in the body of the question as opposed to links.

Comment: Your answers are correct but your graph for part a is not. The equation of the line is $y=1+2x$, which is a straight line, not a curve.

Comment: Could you show me the right way? Of course, if not ask too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An integral, by definition, is the area under a curve. I believe for part (a), you had graphed $1+2x$ as a curve instead of a line. 1+2x is actually a line with slope $2$, and y-intercept at $(0,1)$. To geometrically find the area, all you have to do is find the area from the $x$-axis to the line's boundary, which would simply be a trapezoid with vertices $(1,0), (3,0), (1,3),$ and $(3,7)$. Does this make sense?

Comment: In this case, from what I understand of his explanation, is this the graphical form of question (a)?https://i.imgur.com/xFujUS6.png

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct!